# Serializing PrinterSettings to string or blob for inserting into a database

Tags: c#, serialization

Using the below code, I can serialize / deserialize PrinterSettings to a file. 
I would like to ask if there's a way to serialize it to a string or byte array or similar instead in order to save it directly into a database.

Thank you!

```
PrinterSettings prtSettings = new PrinterSettings();
prtSettings.PrintFileName = "does not matter, unused if PrintToFile == false";

//serialise
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new         System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(prtSettings.GetType());
using (System.IO.TextWriter txtWriter = new     StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\printerSettings.xml"))
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(txtWriter,prtSettings);
}

//deserialise
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\printerSettings.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    object obj = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
    prtSettings = (PrinterSettings)obj;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a StreamWriter use a [StringWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stringwriter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
string printerSettingText = "";
XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PrinterSettings));
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    xser.Serialize(sw, prtSettings);
    printerSettingText = sw.ToString();
}
```

Deserialization of the object is simple like this

```
string dataToDeserialize = GetYourDataFromDb();
xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PrinterSettings));
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(dataToDeserialize))
{

    PrinterSettings prn = (PrinterSettings)xser.Deserialize(sr);
    Console.WriteLine(prn.PrintFileName);
}
```